# Need help select query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have this query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sort_by) as row
     FROM table_name) a
WHERE 
    row > start_row AND row <= limit_row
```

This query will select anything from `table_name`, starting from `start_row` until `limit_row`, and the result will arranged by the `sort_by` column.

But I also need to add the condition `WHERE column_name = column_value`. And the data arranged by the `sort_by` column can be in either ascending or descending order.

My question is where should I add the condition `column_name = column_value`, and the `ORDER ASC/DESC` in my query?

If my question isn't clear, please ask. Thanks.

Comment: How about adding it to the already-existing `WHERE` clause?

Comment: You would add the filter condition to the inner query. If not then you're row numbers will already be assigned.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i did add another and beside limit_row, and in ms sql management studio return The multi-part identifier "column_name" could not be bound.

Comment: I just made an edit that may resolve any issues. If it doesn't, you NEED to post the table schema (which is a good idea to do anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM
( 
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sort_by DESC) as row
    FROM table_name
    WHERE column_name = column_value
) a
WHERE row > start_row
AND row <= limit_row
ORDER BY a.row DESC
```

The row_number function uses the order to determine the order of the data for numbering purposes; this means the row number order is important to know and understand, especially if you are paging data. Typically, when paging data, you want your ordering so that row 1 is the newest record because you want your first page of data to be the most recent; this generally means the order by on the row number would be descending.

The outer order by only changes the order returned back to you and is really acting only as a display ordering. So, typically, that order by would be ascending when paging data as you are already ordering from newest to oldest.

Also, if you are using a new version of SQL Server, they added a paging feature that performs much better (in my experience) than the row numbering paging used in the past.

Comment: wow thanks Ghost ^^ \m/, but i didnt see query to change the order ASC to DESC?, could you please add that?, then ill mark your answer

Comment: Not exactly sure the intent. You could sort your inner query ascending and your outer descending. If you want the full list sorted from ASC, but the returned list in descending order, you would modify the ASC and DESC as such.

Comment: this is my last question, what the difference ORDER BY sort_by  inside parentheses and ORDER BY a.row?